# Export "summarise_all" results

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a database with 146 lines x 86 variables.

After I run:

```
fs <- database %>% group_by(FS)
fs %>% summarise_all(mean)
```

I only can see the results for the first variables (columns) and I need to write the means for all the variables.

So I want to ask if anyone knows how can I see the results for all the 86 variables and then export these results to a text or excel file.

Comment: Please use dput() and paste the output here, or provide sample data. That'll help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: You just want to "see" them on screen? Try piping into View: `%>% View()` to use the built in table viewer. Or you can write to a file with `%>%` write.table("filename.txt")`. See `?write.table` for more options

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MrFlick, you can view the data by either piping (%>%) view or by typing the following in the console.

```
View(fs)
```

You can write the results to a csv file as follows:

```
write.csv(fs, "fileName.csv")
```

By default, it will write the csv file to your working directory.  You can specify a different location for output as such

```
write.csv(fs,"C://Users//MyDocuments//fileName.csv")
```